# User info from token

Tags: java, oauth

My application uses 3-legged authentication (OAuth).

I have the token (user was redirected to google login page to log in)
How can I get the e-mail address he used to authenticate?

Comment: Are you using any OAuth library (such as [oauth-signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/))?

Answer (score 0):

you should look up user data using the access token. in facebook, the access token starts with user serial, so you can identify user from token directly. (ex. 123456-someStrangeStringBlahBlah...)

so if exposure of user serial is not problem, make token like facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [OpenID attribute exchange](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html). (not OAuth, but Google has a bridge between the two).

See Google's page on [their federated login API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OAuth1.0 you can extract user email from the contactService by making a request to get for example contact group id. The returned response contains the user email encoded:

"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/user_email_here%40gmail.com/base/5f062e1e08cb3123"